# Easiest way to simulate infinite scrolling selector with UWP

Tags: uwp

I am trying to design a control that would allow users to scroll up or down a range of numbers (e.g. 0-2000) with a similar feel of scrolling up or down a list.

I tried to use a `ListView` or `GridView` inside a `Flyout` for this, but it's simply too slow just to load a couple thousand items.

Now I'm thinking the best way might be to simply simulate the list scrolling without actually having any items (i.e. an infinite scrolling selector). Any suggestions on what control to use as a base to implement such an infinite selector?

Answer (score 3):

Here is looped virtualized scroller. It keeps only 5 items so you could add a lot of them. For selection, you may add an event on Item.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    private static int Count = 20;
    private static float ItemSize = 128;

    private Visual _spawnerVisual;
    private readonly List<ItemModel> _items = new List<ItemModel>();
    private readonly List<Item> _selectedItems = new List<Item>();
    private int _index;

    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateItems();
        SetInitialItems();
    }

    private void PopulateItems()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            _items.Add(new ItemModel());
        }
    }

    private void SetInitialItems()
    {
        _index = -5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            KillAtTop(true);
        }
        _spawnerVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Spawner);
    }

    private void KillAtTop(bool atTop)
    {
        if (atTop)
        {
            if (_selectedItems.Count > 4)
            {
                _selectedItems.RemoveAt(0);
                Spawner.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            var index = GetIndex(_index + 3);

            var item = new Item
            {
                Id = index,
                BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)Random.Next(0, 255), (byte)Random.Next(0, 255), (byte)Random.Next(0, 255)),
                ItemSize = ItemSize,
                ItemModel = _items[index],
                OffsetY = (_index + 6) * ItemSize
            };
            _selectedItems.Add(item);
            Spawner.Children.Add(item);
            _index++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_selectedItems.Count > 4)
            {
                _selectedItems.RemoveAt(_selectedItems.Count - 1);
                Spawner.Children.RemoveAt(Spawner.Children.Count - 1);
            }

            var index = GetIndex(_index - 3);

            var item = new Item
            {
                Id = index,
                BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)Random.Next(0, 255), (byte)Random.Next(0, 255), (byte)Random.Next(0, 255)),
                ItemSize = ItemSize,
                ItemModel = _items[index],
                OffsetY = _index * ItemSize
            };
            _selectedItems.Insert(0, item);
            Spawner.Children.Insert(0, item);
            _index--;
        }
    }

    private int GetIndex(int index)
    {
        index = index % _items.Count;
        if (index > _items.Count - 1) return index - _items.Count;
        if (index < 0) return _items.Count + index;
        return index;
    }

    private void Slider_OnSetDelta(float deltaY)
    {
        SetPosition(deltaY);
    }

    public void SetPosition(float offsetY)
    {
        _spawnerVisual.Offset += new Vector3(0, offsetY / 10, 0);

        if (_spawnerVisual.Offset.Y > -ItemSize * _index + ItemSize)
        {
            KillAtTop(false);
        }

        if (_spawnerVisual.Offset.Y < -ItemSize * _index)
        {
            KillAtTop(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Just add your ItemControl and call SetPosition to scroll.
Should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach! Would love to see a GitHub repo though. :P

Comment: second that. What's `Spawner` and how does it all interact? what does the XAML look like? do you have a repo to share?

Comment: @MarkusHütter XAML is a page with 1 Canvas named Spawner. I got no repo. I've done it just for fun

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use a ListView or GridView inside a Flyout for this, but it's simply too slow just to load a couple thousand items.

For your requirement, you do not have to create all the items at once.
You can load the remaining items as needed via implement [`ISupportIncrementalLoading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ISupportIncrementalLoading) interface. It allows to easily create a collection in which data is loaded incrementally, when a user is about to the end of the items available on the user interface. Using it, we can obtain a fast & fluid scrolling while loading an huge set of records.

```
public class ItemToShow : ObservableCollection<string>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    public int lastItem = 1;

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (lastItem == 2000) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        var progressBar = ((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage).MyProgressBar;
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(() =>
       {
           coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
           {
               progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
               progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
           });
           List<string> items = new List<string>();
           for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               items.Add(string.Format("Items{0}", lastItem));
               lastItem++;
               if (lastItem == 2000)
                   break;
           }
           coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
           {
               foreach (string item in items)
               {
                   this.Add(item);
                   progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                   progressBar.IsHoldingEnabled = false;
               }
           });
           return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };
       }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView
        x:Name="ListViewMain"
        Margin="0,100,0,0"
        Padding="100,0,0,10">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateListViewMain">
                <Grid
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Background="LightGray">
                    <TextBlock
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="18"
                        Text="{Binding}"
                        TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataTemplateListViewMain" />
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ProgressBar
        x:Name="MyProgressBar"
        Height="10"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     ListViewMain.ItemsSource = new ItemToShow();
 }
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really interesting approach that I had never seen before and I really hoped it would work. Unfortunately, it still hangs my `Flyout`. By setting breakpoints I see that the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method is called in quick succession, first with `count = 1`, then 3, 12, 48, 192, etc, until the whole sequence is unfolded without me even trying to scroll the list.

Comment: Even more interesting, this weird behavior doesn't happen if I place the `ListView` outside the `Flyout`, so it seems the eager unfolding is coming from the `Flyout` class.

Comment: Yep, I have not placed the listview in the Flyout. And I think that it is  irrational design to render too much  items in the Flyout.

Comment: I agree, that is why my original question was asking how to create an infinite looping selector for picking out numbers in a range. I mentioned the `ListView` inside the `Flyout` simply as an illustration of what kind of things I already tried.