# c# UWP parallel image loading

Tags: c#, uwp, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a C# UWP solution for myself and I have defined the special manifest `broadFileSystemAccess`, so I can access all files from my PC directly.

Now I'm loading a bunch of image files into memory in order to show them on a `GridView`. At this task needs a lot of time, I would like to speed it up by running it parallel.

```
foreach (var item in someList)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(item.ImagePath);
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    }

    someOtherList.Add(new someModel { ... });
};
```

On some other thread I found the usage of `Parallel.ForEach` - but that does not support async calls. Then I saw a library called `Dasync` with `using Dasync.Collections`. However using this function just throws an error saying something about an interface that was marshalled for another thread that was called by the application (roughly translated), so I figured that library might not be suitable for this task either.

How would I parallelize this in a C# UWP application?

Comment: *Don't* load them unless you want to display them. Besides, you can't modify a UI element from another thread *in any OS*, so you wan't gain much if you load everything in parallel. In the end, they'll be displayed one by one

Comment: The *real* solution is to use the scroll and data virtualization features in every grid to load items only when you need to display them. Photo applications that display hundreds of photos work this way - they only load the data they need to display

Comment: PS your disk won't run faster if you use multiple cores, which means you won't get the speedup you expect even for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *start* all tasks and then wait for them all to complete using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
Func<Item, Task<BitmapImage>> f = async (item) =>
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(item.ImagePath);
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return bitmapImage;
};

BitmapImage[] bitmapImages = await Task.WhenAll(someList.Select(f).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading a large number of images at once, it will consume a lot of system memory. Using multiple tasks to read different images at the same time, it also consumes system resource.

The best practice is that using data cut way read files. For example, read 10 images once, next time read other 10 images. And GridView is virtualization control that could release the memory when the item scroll out of the display air. For more information, you can refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498101/7254781).